# Using double colon to create a row array and then transpose to a column array

Tags: arrays, matlab, transpose

The full question is:
Construct a row array `countValues` with elements `1` to `endValue`, using the double colon operator. Transpose `countValues` to result in a column array.

and my attempt is:

```
countValues = 1:endValue;
countValues' ;   % the ' is for transposing
```

I keep submitting this into the zybook but it says my answer remains as a row array and does not transpose.

Comment: `'` is not for transpose. `.'` is

Comment: pretty sure the textbook said   arrayname' ;   will transpose it idk if the   .' works tho

Comment: The way you do that, assign the column vector to the automatic variable `ans`, but `countValues`  does not change and remains as a row. Try `countValues=countValues.'` . The `.'` notation is sometimes preferable because it has only one meaning, while `'` can be olso conjugate values in complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

NVM y'all I got the answer

it seems I had to overwrite the old array in order to keep the transposing 
so the correct way to transpose this was:

countValues = countValues' ;

Comment: Overwriting has nothing to do with *the correct way* of transposing. You just needed to submit the transposed array